# How to update the Unicode data into SQL Server by PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode

I using sqlsrv driver to connect the Microsoft SQL Sever 2008 R2 by PHP.
But, i tried to update the information by update statement. it doesn't work
It seems that i cannot update the information with non-English words. Such as Chinese word.
The database doesn't updated.

It works.

```
$query="UPDATE [Management].[dbo].[Employee]
   SET [Management].[dbo].[Employee].[name] = 'abc'
 WHERE [Management].[dbo].[Employee].[EmpID]=1;";
$stmt=sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
```

It not work.

```
$query="UPDATE [Management].[dbo].[Employee]
   SET [Management].[dbo].[Employee].[name] = '你好'
 WHERE [Management].[dbo].[Employee].[EmpID]=1;";
$stmt=sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
```

Comment: i found the solution! The full solution is make sure your Column's Datatype is 'NVARCHAR' or 'NCHAR'(from @M.Ali). Also, you need to add the N-flag during insert Unicode data. The most import thing is set `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` in the connection code. Like this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [N flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms186939.aspx) (nvarchar, ntext...) in table field type for unicode support, and add N flag on query

```
$query = "UPDATE [Management].[dbo].[Employee]
          SET [Management].[dbo].[Employee].[name] = N'你好'
          WHERE [Management].[dbo].[Employee].[EmpID]=1;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
```

In html page use charset utf8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But, still doesn't works.
i paste the sql into studio. it works, but doesn't work on php

Comment: the page charset is utf8?? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: i don't know why i built the table by using `nvarchar` to storage chinese word, and add "N" in insert data(chinese). I cannot display the correct word by set charset to utf8, i need set Big5 to show the correct chinese word

Answer (score 2):

Whenever Dealing with Unicode Characters in Sql Server you need to prefix your passed strings with `N` to tell sql server that passed string can contain some unicode characters ..

For example

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Column1 NVARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(N'你好')  -- With N Prefix
,('你好')  -- Without N Prefix

SELECT * FROM @Table

╔═════════╗
║ Column1 ║
╠═════════╣
║ 你好     ║  -- With N Prefix
║ ??      ║  -- Without N Prefix
╚═════════╝
```

Similarly when you are updating you will need to prefix the string with `N` something like this

```
UPDATE [Management].[dbo].[Employee]
   SET [name] = N'你好'
 WHERE [EmpID]=1;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But, still doesn't works.
i paste the sql into studio. it works, but doesn't work on php

Comment: @user2520217 You need to make sure your Column's Datatype is `NVARCHAR` or `NCHAR`, because you cannot store unicode character in VARCHAR or CHAR datatype columns.

Comment: Column Name:name,,,
DataType : nvarchar(6) null